# Vb 2015 query with parameters not working

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, prepared-statement

I already used parametrized queries with no problem, but today I'm stuck on an error that I cannot debug.
This is my working query

```
cmd.CommandText = "select idcliente, ragsociale from Clienti where idcliente =" & strName & " or codiceamministrazione='" & strName & "' or piva='" & strName & "' or codfisc='" & strName & "'"
```

The same, but with parameter, not working

```
cmd.CommandText = "select idcliente, ragsociale from Clienti where idcliente = @Cliente or codiceamministrazione=@Cliente or piva=@Cliente or codfisc=@Cliente"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente", strName)
```

I use this in an autocomplete procedure that shows the name of a client based on internal id or on commercial license number (and other similar codes). On the db a client record can have all the code fields compiled or just 1.

With the non-parametrized query the autocomplete suggestion pop-up,with the parametrized one nothing shows. No errors either.

**EDIT:**
using this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cliente", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters("@Cliente").Value = strName
```

now another query (omitted before for semplicity) in the same function works, but, strange enough, the one for what I did this question don't.

Working:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select idcliente, ragsociale from Clienti where ragsociale like '%'+@Cliente+'%' or codiceamministrazione=@Cliente"
```

Still not Working:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select idcliente, ragsociale from Clienti where idcliente = @Cliente or piva=@Cliente or codfisc=@Cliente"
```

Comment: You know you can just rewrite that to `where @Cliente in(idcliente, codiceamministrazione, piva, codfisc)`

Comment: Please, don't use .AddWithValue! I think, this is the problem.

Comment: [Joel Coehoorn's blog post](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) to reiterate what muffi is saying.

Comment: Thank you all, I edited my question

Comment: doesn't work with what inputs exactly? In your original query, when testing against idcliente, you treat strName as a number (no quotes round it), but for all the other fields you treat it like a string. So you're implying it could potentially contain an int or a string. This is potentially problematic, if you type a number, and the query now treats it like a string, it won't match the numeric value of idclient in the DB and therefore you may get no results.

Comment: @ADyson it make even less sense... in **codiceamministrazione=Cliente** the value can be like "AUX72ZA" (so it's a string) but the query containing that bit is working, instead in **where idcliente = Cliente or piva=Cliente or codfisc=Cliente** it's a string of all numbers and the query containing this bit isn't working

Comment: like I said, if your input is a number, but your query thinks they're a string (because of the data type in the param), they will not match against any numeric field in the database. `12345 != "12345"`. Potentially you need to define separate parameters for these scenarios. You can pass the same value into them, but in one case set the parameter's datatype to varchar and in the other case to int (you might need to check if the value can be parsed as a number before you do this, otherwise it will likely crash. In that case just set it null or 0 or something that won't make an accidental match).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I ended up adding 2 parameters, one for string research and the other for int research. Now it's working. Convert your comment in answer so I can sign it as correct answer, thanks

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino done, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original query, when testing against `idcliente`, you treat `strName` as a number (no quotes round it), but for all the other fields you treat it like a string. So you're implying it could potentially contain a number or a string. This is problematic, if you type a number, and the parameterised version of the query now treats it like a string in all cases, then it won't match the numeric value of `idcliente` in the DB and therefore you may get no results.

To clarify: if your input is a number, but your query thinks it's a string (because of the data type in the param), it will not match against any numeric field in the database. `12345 != "12345"`.

You need to define separate parameters for these scenarios. You can pass the same value into them, but in one case set the parameter's datatype to varchar and in the other case to int (you might need to check if the value can be parsed as a number before you do this, otherwise it will likely crash. In that case just set it null or 0 or something that won't make an accidental match).